# Looping through list of dictionary in python

Tags: list, dictionary

Given list of dictionary in python

```
my_list=[{'id':0,'name':'cube0_cluster0','member_ids': [429, 432, 435]}, 
{'id': 1,'name': 'cube0_cluster1','member_ids': [0, 4, 5]}, 
{'id':0,'name':'cube1_cluster1','member_ids': [4, 706, 800]}]
```

I want to print all `member_ids` for `cube{ }_cluster1`

My expected output is to print `[0,4,5,706,800]`

any help would be highly appreciated

I have tried it

`for k in my_list:
    for j in range(len(my_list)):
        if k['name']=='cube{}_cluster1'.format(j):
            print(k['member_ids'])`

But I am getting two separate outputs as `[0,4,5]` and `[4,706,800]`

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) What is your question? Do not ask us to write code for you.

Comment: Next time may be too late and this question will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
import re    
member_ids = []
for di in my_list:
    if re.match('cube\d_cluster1', di['name']):
        member_ids += di['member_ids']
print(member_ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can  also use list comprehension.

```
my_list=[{'id':0,'name':'cube0_cluster0','member_ids': [429, 432, 435]}, 
{'id': 1,'name': 'cube0_cluster1','member_ids': [0, 4, 5]}, 
{'id':0,'name':'cube1_cluster1','member_ids': [4, 706, 800]}]


res = [j for i in my_list for j in i['member_ids'] if "cluster1" in i["name"]]

print (res) # return list
print (set(res)) # to return distinct data

# Result
# [0, 4, 5, 4, 706, 800]
# {0, 800, 706, 4, 5}
```

I hope this helps and counts!